# NTVDM.exe command prompt switches

Tags: ntvdm

I have an old program designed for DOS running on my WinXP PC under NTVDM.
Recently it began showing some strange behaviour and I decided to investigate the problem.

However, none of the search results has documentation on NTVDM itself, apart from brief explanation of what it is, even microsoft.com.

Right now I want to know what command prompt switches exist for it (my program runs with `-f -i5`) and how to use them.

I've tried running ntvdm from command line with switches like `-?`, `-h` or `-help`, but no output is given.

So, the question is:
1) What command prompt switches exist for ntvdm.exe and what they mean?
2) What `-f -i5` switch does in particular?

Edit: added OS

Comment: what version of windows are you using? MS removed 16-bit support (ntvdm) from windows in 2010. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS10-015 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/advisory/979682

Comment: Windows XP SP3. 
It's a legacy software that's not really easy to replace

Answer (score 1):

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102986, the only available switches are `-a -f -m -w`. The definition is supplied.

No mention of `-i` switch, though.

I'll try to find more info on this subject, as legacy DOS software still in use is not that rare find

According to http://dis.4chan.org/read/prog/1238681773 there is indeed undocumented `-i` switch in use.

Comment: It would be nice if you briefly quoted the resources you've found. Microsoft can withdraw its legacy documentation at any time, and 4chan.org is unavailable often enough.

Comment: @Vladimir Tsuverkalov - Both the above references are no longer available I would like to know the meaning of the command line options (also just curious). Do you have a copy of the information ?